# Debugging Simple C++ Function

Tags: c++, debugging, tokenize

I wrote a simple program to remind me the basics, but it's only returning 0 in my vector. I'm having a hard time finding out why, as I'm not super familiar with the string search functions.

(User enters a single string of numbers separated by spaces, function should find and substring the numbers by locating the spaces.)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
vector<int> ParsePrompt(string sInput)
{
    vector<int> vOutput;
    string sSubstring;
    int iPosition = 0;
    for (int iLocated = sInput.find(" ", iPosition); iLocated != string::npos; iLocated = sInput.find(" ", iLocated))
    {
        sSubstring = sInput.substr(iPosition, (iLocated - 1)); // Substring from our starting position to before the space found.
        int iSubstring = atoi(sSubstring.c_str()); // Convert our string to its numeric form.
        vOutput.push_back(iSubstring); // Push it into our vector.
        iLocated++; // Move past last space.
        iPosition = iLocated; // Record our new starting position.
    }
    return vOutput;
}
```

Here's how I'm calling it, it's printing a single "0"

```
cout << endl << "You entered: ";
for (auto item:vFirstPrompt)
{
    cout << item << " "; // Iterate through our indices and print them
}
```

I know there's a stupid rookie logic mistake here... just can't find it!

I would also be happy to know if someone knows a simpler way of sorting through a string and substringing between spaces into individual items.

Comment: "substringing between spaces" is commonly known as "tokenizing" if you're looking for a search term to use.

Comment: so since your question is tagged `debugging`, did you debug your program?

Comment: you seem to be trying to return (hopefully) a vector to a variable and have the type handled naturally by 'auto'...your compiler should be arguing with you about that at the very least...is it?  What are your error messages when you try to compile?

Comment: The second parameter of `substr` function takes the length, not the index.

Comment: Remember all the groovy stuff you can do with `std::cin` to read input from the user token by token?  Well, you can use `std::istringstream` to make a stream out of a string. Then you can `while (stream >> iSubstring)  vOutput.push_back(iSubstring);` Stops dead when it runs out of string or it hits a token that can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll play around with the istringstream and token methods for a bit and see if I can't do this a smarter way. It's only a learning exercise for myself. It's been 8 years since I programmed. In regards to debugging, I might not have correctly used that tag... I'm not getting any errors, only unexpected results. Apologies for any confusion.